# PostgreSql Russian dict gor fulltext search

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, utf-8, sequence, cyrillic

I tried to add Russian dictionary for fulltext search in postgresql db. I' ve downloaded dict files, converted them to UTF-8 and tried to create new dict

```
$ iconv -f koi8-r -t utf-8 < ru_RU.aff > /opt/local/share/postgresql93/tsearch_data/russian.affix
$ iconv -f koi8-r -t utf-8 < ru_RU.dic > /opt/local/share/postgresql93/tsearch_data/russian.dict


CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY russian_ispell (
   TEMPLATE = ispell,
   DictFile = russian,
   AffFile = russian,
   StopWords = russian
);
```

But got an ERROR:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd1
CONTEXT:  line 341 of configuration file "/opt/local/share/postgresql93/tsearch_data/russian.affix": "SFX Y   хаться шутся        хаться"
```

Then tried with other Russian dicts, but the same error occurred. How can I handle with this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute the following command:

```
    export LC_ALL=C
```

I think you have a locale issue. This command should be executed in the same command line session where you execute the command for creating dictionary.